# How to modify the TimeDateStamp field in PE file header?

Tags: python, portable-executable, compilation-time

I am writing a python program to modify the compilation time of PE files. Based on my research, the compilation time is stored in the file header under the TimeDateStamp field. However, I only managed to find ways to read the TimeDateStamp value.

For example,

```
import pe

filename = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.exe"
pe = pefile.PE(filename)
print("TimeDateStamp: "+hex(pe.FILE_HEADER.TimeDateStamp))
```

How can I edit the TimeDateStamp field in the PE file header instead?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the way to modify the timedatestamp field in PE file header by slightly modifying the code from [getPETimeStamp.py created by @geudrik](https://gist.github.com/geudrik/03152ba1a148d9475e81).

**Python 3**

```
import pefile
from struct import unpack
from binascii import hexlify, a2b_uu

# Reference: https://github.com/deptofdefense/SalSA/wiki/PE-File-Format
def getTimeDateStamp(filename):
    pe = pefile.PE(filename)
    print("TimeDateStamp: "+hex(pe.FILE_HEADER.TimeDateStamp))

# Reference: https://gist.github.com/geudrik/03152ba1a148d9475e81
def writeTimeDateStamp(filename, newTimeDateStamp):
    # Open file in read or write binary mode r+b
    try:
        filehandle = open(filename, 'r+b')
        # Check that file opened is Portable Executable file
        if hexlify(filehandle.read(2)) != hexlify(bytes('MZ', encoding="utf8")):
            filehandle.close()
            print("File is not in PE format!")
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return

    # Find the offset of the timeDateStamp and write into it
    try:
        # Get PE offset (@60, DWORD) from DOS header
        #   It's little-endian so we have to flip it
        #   We also need the HEX representation which is an INT value
        filehandle.seek(60, 0)
        offset = filehandle.read(4)
        offset = hexlify(offset[::-1])

        # This was added in due to an issue with offset being set to '' on rare occasions (see comments below)
        if offset == '':
            print("offset is empty")
            filehandle.close()
            return

        #   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''
        #   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826054/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-16-x0e-xa3-python
        #   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375706/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-python
        #       This indicates that for some reason, 'offset' from above is being set as '' and thus can't be converted to a base 16 int
        offset = int(offset, 16)

        # Seek to PE header and read second DWORD
        filehandle.seek(offset+8, 0)
        filehandle.write(newTimeDateStamp)
        filehandle.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return

getTimeDateStamp("test.exe")
# Changing timeDateStamp field to 5c4570dd
writeTimeDateStamp("test.exe", bytes.fromhex('dd70455c'))
getTimeDateStamp("test.exe")
```

Using the code above, the timeDateStamp field will be changed to 5c4570dd.

Answer (score 0):

pefile supports updating the original file, this one does not need to deal with NT header offsets:

```
import pefile

pe = pefile.PE("test.exe")
pe.FILE_HEADER.TimeDateStamp = 1348054607
pe.write("new.exe")
```

Also, Your code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Hex Editor? You can easily modify any value of any field provided that you know the offset of the field.

I believe the TimeDateStamp field is located 2 bytes away from the NumberOfSections field which is located 2 bytes away from the Machine field.

Very simple.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31454125)